# Call another field from one to many table Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a problem here. How can i call the field 'username' from the user table? I want to show the username here not the user_id. Here the pict : 
[I want to show the username not the user_id in part 'Direquest oleh' and 'Disetujui/Ditolak oleh'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyCGl.jpg)

and here my code :

```
[
            'attribute' => 'waktu_request',
            'label' => 'Waktu Request',
            'format' => ['DateTime', 'php:d M Y H:i:s'],
            'filter' => '',
        ],
        [
            'attribute'=>'requested_by',
            'label' => 'Direquest oleh',
            'value' => function($model){
                if($model->requested_by == NULL){
                    return '-';
                }else{
                    return $model->requested_by;
                }
            }
        ],
        [
            'attribute'=>'approved_rejected_by',
            'label' => 'Disetujui/Ditolak oleh',
            'value' => function($model){
                if($model->approved_rejected_by == NULL){
                    return '-';
                }else{
                    return $model->approved_rejected_by;
                }
            }
        ],
```

I hope anyone can solve my problem here. For your attention i say thank you.

Comment: those `requested_by`, `approved_rejected_by` are foreign keys to `user` table, aren't they? If yes, you should name it appropriately like `requested_by_id`, and then in gii `getRequestedBy()` relation should be generated. By using that relation you can call `$model->requestedBy->username` or whatelse you need from your relational model

Comment: Yess solved, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had used Gii to generate model and crud you probably already have relation generated named `getRequestedBy()` and `getApprovedRejectedBy()`.

```
[
    'attribute'=>'requested_by',
    'label' => 'Direquest oleh',
    'value' => function($model){
        return ($model->requested_by) ? $model->requestedBy->username : '-';
    }
],
[
    'attribute'=>'approved_rejected_by',
    'label' => 'Disetujui/Ditolak oleh',
    'value' => function($model){
        return ($model->approved_rejected_by) ? $model->approvedRejectedBy->username : '-';
    }
],
```

Don't forget to add relation in searchModel for eager loading aka reduce no of queries. For example,

```
ModelName::find()->with(['requestedBy', 'approvedRejectedBy']);
```

Answer (score -2):

First of all you need to create a function in your model class,like as

```
public function getCreatedByText()
    {
        $user = User::findOne($this->created_by);
        if ($user != null) {
            return $user->username;
        }
        return '-';
    }
```

Then your assign this function like that

```
'label' => 'Created At',
'value' =>  $model->getCreatedAtText()
```

if you don't have understand,please let me know.I will try my best.

Comment: That's not good solution. Right now, more than one use generates more and more SQL queries about `User`. Proper way is set up relation by this foreign key (`created_by`), and use it as relation `$model->user ? $model->user->username : '-'`.

Comment: you can create a query for foreign key related data in this function and return your desire string.After that you using this function in value.

Comment: Yes, you did it, and it's wrong. As i said, **every call to this function will fire another DB query**. Proper way of doing such things is relations in Yii2.